# Link to kernel32.dll using ld.exe

Tags: assembly, gcc, nasm, ld, kernel32

I have assembled my assembly program using the following command:

`nasm -f win64 -o test.obj test.asm`

test.asm contains a few functions that call Win32 functions like GetStdHandle, HeapAlloc, etc

Normally, I would link one of my assembly projects like so:

`ld -LC:/Windows/System32 -lkernel32 -e main -o test.exe test.obj`

And it produces a `test.exe` file, as expected.

However, once I begin to use Win32 functions *making use of the heap*, like HeapAlloc, HeapFree, GetProcessHeap, I get the following error when linking:

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: ertr000016.o:(.rdata+0x0): undefined reference to '_pei386_runtime_relocator'`

I was then able to assume it has to do with MinGW's files being linked in. So I tried to compile it without them:

`ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -LC:/Windows/System32 -lkernel32 -e main -o test.exe test.obj`

and get the following error:

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32`

So, my question is: how am I supposed to link to kernel32 using ld.exe (without including startfiles or stdlib), because no matter what I try I cannot get it to work.

Thank you for your help!

*(I would like an answer that doesn't just tell me use **GoLink**, please, unless that is the only possible solution).*

Comment: Shouldn't you specify an *import file* to link to? They are usually in the MinGW installation directory, not in `%SYSTEM32%`.

Comment: Instead of `-LC:/Windows/System32 -lkernel32` you can try `C:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I believe it is the MinGW import library (libkernel32.a) that causes the problem.

Comment: @RossRidge When I replaced it, get: `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: ertr000016.o:(.rdata+0x0): undefined reference to '_pei386_runtime_relocator'`

Comment: That means the error isn't caused by MinGW files being linked in, but caused because they're not.

Comment: @RossRidge I guess so. But what I am trying to do is to compile this application without having to link to MinGW

Comment: You can build your own `libkernel32.a` file using `dlltool.exe`. The Windows variants of the binutils suite (that contains `ld.exe`) should contain `dlltool.exe`. Unfortunately, you have to write the `.def` file (containing a list of functions in the DLL file you want to import) manually.

Comment: @MartinRosenau How I would go about using `dlltool.exe` to generate my own `libkernel32.a`?

Comment: This comment was originally on a now deleted answer, but I'l repeat here in case it's helpful to anyone: .. the original poster's problem is the result of the linker determining that the generated executable needs runtime relocations applied for some reason and so arranged for it to call `_pei386_runtime_relocator` at start up (probably through a TLS initialization routine) to do this relocation. It may have nothing to do with the options passed to the linker and instead be an issue with the code being assembled

Comment: @RossRidge Is there any way I can go about fixing this issue (even linking with `_pei386_runtime_relocator` if necessary)? The other answer (by Martin Rosenau) is still giving me segfaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that the answer is in the comments now, but I'll post all the steps here just to be clear:

1. Create a `.def` file for the DLL to be used. This can be done like this:

```
LIBRARY [name of the dll]
EXPORTS
    [required export #1]
    [required export #2]
    [etc.]
```

2. Use `dlltool.exe` to create an archive library file for the `.def` file:

```
dlltool -d "[path to the .def file]" -l "[path to output file C, defined below]"
```

In this command, `C` is `libXXX.a`, with `XXX` changed out for a different name (preferably the name of the original dll without the extension).

3. Instead of using `ld.exe`, use the linker built into `gcc.exe`. Also, change out the directory after `-L` for the directory containing the `libXXX.a` archive file(s) and change out the dll names that follow for the `XXX` that was replaced in `libXXX.a`. These steps, in the context of the original problem, would be:

```
[Kernel32.def file]

LIBRARY KERNEL32.DLL
EXPORTS
    HeapAlloc
    HeapFree
    [...]
```

```
dlltool -d "kernel32.def" -l "libkernel32.a"
```

```
gcc -LC:/path/to/this/directory/ -lkernel32 -e main -o test.exe test.obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on `Cygwin` trying to make `SDL2` work

and installing `w32api`/`w32api-headers`/`w32api-runtime` packages has fixed the issue.

It provides the necessary headers and lib files *which `Cygwin`'s `gcc` knows where to find (`"/usr/lib/w32api/"`)*.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> ... -LC:/Windows/System32 -lkernel32 ...
> ```

This is definitely wrong: `-lkernel32` will not search for a DLL file named `kernel32.dll`, but for a library file named `libkernel32.a`.

... and `libkernel32.a` is surely not located in `C:/Windows/System32`.

> How I would go about using `dlltool.exe` to generate my own `libkernel32.a`?

For 64-bit Windows this is easier than for 32-bit Windows (because in 32-bit Windows the fuctions are named differently in the DLL and in the object files).

First, you create a definition file (`.def`) that looks like this:

```
LIBRARY KERNEL32.DLL
EXPORTS
    HeapAlloc
    HeapFree
    GetProcessHeap
    CreateFileA
    ReadFile
```

There is a 3rd party tool that can read a `.dll` file and generate a `.def` file containing all functions of the DLL; however, you can do this manually and only add the functions that you need.

Then run the following command line:

```
dlltool -d kernel32.def -l libkernel32.a
```

Unfortunately, I cannot tell you if this solves your problem with `_pei386_runtime_relocator`.

**EDIT**

> ```
> undefined reference to 'SetFilePointer'
> ```

`SetFilePointer` is also a function defined in `kernel32.dll`. Did you add `SetFilePointer` to the `.def` file?

```
LIBRARY KERNEL32.DLL
EXPORTS
    HeapAlloc
    HeapFree
    GetProcessHeap
    CreateFileA
    ReadFile
    SetFilePointer     <-- HERE?
```

> I am linking with the following command:

There may be a second problem:

Some versions of `gcc` require the command line arguments in a certain order. Maybe this is true for `ld`, too.

Try to move the `-L` and `-l` argument to the end of the line:

```
ld ... -o test.exe test.o -L... -lkernel32
```

Comment: When I link to the generated `libkernel32.a`, I get a bunch of errors:

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ld.exe: test.o:test.asm:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to 'SetFilePointer'`, among others

Comment: I am linking with the following command: `ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -L{dir_containing_generated_libkernel32.a} -lkernel32 -e main -o test.exe test.o`

Comment: Doing so gives me a segmentation fault. I disassembled the file and everything looked normal (at least I think so). What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Let me clarify. When I disassembled with `objdump`, it didn't show anything out of the ordinary. But when I ran the program with `gdb`, it showed that the first line of execution was not what it was supposed to be. Was my code getting **relocated**?

Comment: Or rather, is it because my code is **not being relocated**

Comment: @Ark But linking works well. Did you check in `gdb` if the first instruction executed is the first instruction you expect? Did you check in which instruction you get a segmentation fault?

Comment: *I ran the program with gdb, it showed that the first line of execution was not what it was supposed to be.* This **first** line was something along the lines of `mov al, byte[eax]` instead of `push rbp`, which is also where the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: @Ark It looks like a 32-bit `.exe` file has been produced, which cannot work if your assembly code is 64-bit. You can check this using `objdump -f filename.exe`. If the output shows `architecture: i386:x86-64` (or similar), this is not a problem. If it shows `architecture: i386`, this is at least one problem.

Comment: @MatrinRosenau mine says `architecture: i386:x86-64`, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @Ark Can you upload your assembly file and the resulting `.exe` file to somewhere so we can examine it?

Comment: @MatrinRosenau **test.asm:** https://pastebin.com/G80pwFvr *utils64_release.asm:* https://pastebin.com/U8QfJfvR

Comment: @MatrinRosenau I'd also like to note that it seems the segmentation fault only occurs the very first time I run the program after being compiled. Run again after that does not produce any segfaults (which is strange behaviour).

Comment: @Ark -- Hello. Did you ever find a solution to the 'Segmentation fault' error? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ link your application with gcc using -nostartfiles (and maybe also -nodefaultlibs, not 100% sure though) and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: @Ark -- I tried your suggestions without much success. But thanks for replying.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ Did you use `-e <entry_point>` to specify the entry point for your assembly application? And again, make sure you're using `gcc.exe` to link *instead* of `ld.exe`, while still using `nasm.exe` to assemble/compile.